# how to install phonegap with command prompt

Tags: node.js, phonegap-desktop-app

Hi I tried to install phonegap after downloding node.js from the website and I keep getting this error message as displayed in the picture below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iMZr.png)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Obviously NPM can not find some needed files, for someone to help you, you should include npm_debug.log output in your question

Comment: I am sorry were can I find the npm_debug.log ?

Comment: usually in the directory where you called npm, so in your case your home directory. If you can’t find the file, let windows search for you by filename.